# Computer doesn't boot with Xiaomi 34' 21:9 144hz monitor

Tags: boot, nvidia, multiple-monitors

I'm new here, i have a problem with ubuntu, recently i've installed ubuntu 21.04 (last version) my problem is that when i boot my computer and i have xiaomi monitor connected to graphic card, computer doesn't boot, but when i disconnected it and reboot it starts good, i can see it on another monitor that i have. Once computer is started, i can connect my xiaomi monitor and any problem. Just can't put it at 144hz, just 100hz.

Don't know which can be the problem. If someone knows i would appreciate some help.

Comment: How is it connected to your computer?  Most HDMI cables and ports don't support that bandwidth

Comment: @Nmath both monitors are connected with DP, i had no problem with windows 10. Just with ubuntu